# Exporting Gcal with Colours

Tags: colors, calendar, google-calendar-api

Is there any way to export colours from Goggle Calander and post them into Goggle Sheets - I've seen posts from 2019 from various sites saying that this functionality was impossible, but I use colours to break up my calendar and I would love to bring colours over to help with my stats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this guide:

1. Create a [new](https://sheets.new) Google Sheet
2. Create a new [Bound Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) via `Extensions > Apps Script`
3. Activate [Advanced Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) for accesing [Calendar API Colors](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/colors)
4. Copy this code in:

```js
const sS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
function bringCalendarToSheet() {
  // Getting the colors for the Calendar and Events
  const colors = Calendar.Colors.get()
  const colorsCalendar = colors.calendar
  const colorsEvents = colors.event
  // Parsing and setting the data for the Calendar Colors
  const A1 = sS.getRange('A1').setValue('Calendar Colors')
  const colorsCalendarLength = Object.keys(colorsCalendar).length
  const rCC = sS.getRange(2, 1, 1, colorsCalendarLength).setBackgrounds([Object.keys(colorsCalendar).map(k => {
    return colorsCalendar[k].background
  })])
  // Parsing and setting the data for the Event Colors
  const A3 = sS.getRange('A3').setValue('Event Colors')
  const colorsEventsLength = Object.keys(colorsEvents).length
  const rEC = sS.getRange(4, 1, 1, colorsEventsLength).setBackgrounds(
    [Object.keys(colorsEvents).map(k => {
      return colorsEvents[k].background
    })]
  )
}
```

This will show all Calendar available colors:

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thankyou - is there a way to bring in colour used over a certain date range?

Comment: Sure, you only have to use JS to do it, but I think that needs to be posted in another question. If my answer was helpful to you, consider up-voting/accepting it.

Comment: Thanks will do and what is JS - Java Script? Yep I will ask that - thankyou for helping